# trigger('click') not working on datepickerrange calendar item

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

i'm using the calendar from http://www.daterangepicker.com/ an try to click programatically a specific date.

strange is, that i can set a .css('border','1px solid red') with the following code. **but why is the .trigger('click') not working?**

```
$(".daterangepicker").find("[data-title='" + item + "']").trigger('click');
$(".daterangepicker").find("[data-title='" + item + "']").css('border','1px solid red');
```

> **i think this is an datepickerrange issue, can anybody help?**

the reason why i want to do this is, that i have an inline calendar.
[image]

and if in this calendar an item was clicked, i open the popup calender in the right form. the css border works, but i cant make the date active with .trigger('click')
[image]

> **here is a pen: https://codepen.io/exotec/pen/rrjNVY** in JS search for these 2 lines:

```
$("#original .daterangepicker "+parentClass).find("[data-title='" + item + "']").trigger('click');
$("#original .daterangepicker "+parentClass).find("[data-title='" + item + "']").css('border','1px solid red');
```

Comment: Can you share your working code?

Comment: i have added a pen at the end of my question

Answer (score -1):

because the click do not work, i set now a new startdate by the value of clicked date.

```
// build startdate
var monthAndYear = parent.find('.month').text();
monthAndYear = monthAndYear.split(' ');
var day = $(this).text();
var month = moment().month(monthAndYear[0]).format("MM");
var year = monthAndYear[1]

// set startdate
var drp = $('#daterange').data('daterangepicker');
var start = moment(year+'-'+month+'-'+day);
// console.log(month);
// console.log(year);
drp.startDate = start;
drp.endDate = null;
drp.updateView();
drp.updateCalendars();
```